# Visual Studio Typescript with npm and node modules packages referencing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript

So I using typescript for ASP NET MVC project, the typescript is managing front end JS and also angularJs.

I have a viewmodels folder contain many `.ts` files. So I try to separate them and host it under private npm package.

Next, I use npm to download them into `node_modules` folders but the referencing for these typescript viewmodels is not working anymore.

Say all ts is under same namespace. just one part is local typescript folder, another part is node modules folder.

The action I taken since problem appear

1. Project include /node_modules/@privatescope/viewmodels/*.ts and also *.js
2. Make sure bundles is targeting  node_modules/@privatescope/viewmodels/*.js
3. project can debug and work like previous, but my local typescript cannot get proper reference

I also try with this in my local typescript file

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/@privatescope/viewmodels/CurrencyViewModel.ts" />
```

or even this

```
var currencyViewModel = require("node_modules/@privatescope/viewmodels/CurrencyViewModel.ts")

// error here
export class CurrencyRepository extends Repository<currencyViewModel> implements IRepository<currencyViewModel>
```

both doesn't help me solve referencing issue and tslint too.

// my tsconfig

```
{
   "compileOnSave": true,
   "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
        "dom",
        "es5",
        "scripthost",
        "es6"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    //"strictNullChecks": true,
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "obj",
    "bin"
]
}



// viewmodel in node_module
namespace test.data {
'use strict';
    export class CurrencyViewModel extends CurrencyGenViewModel { 
    }
}

//base class also in mode_module

'use strict';

namespace test.data {
    export interface IGenCurrencyViewModel { 
        CurrencyRates: CurrencyRateGenViewModel[];
        Id: number;
        Name: string;
        CurrencyCode: string;
    }

    export class CurrencyGenViewModel implements IGenCurrencyViewModel, ICurrency { 
    public CurrencyRates: CurrencyRateGenViewModel[];
    public Id: number;
    public Name: string;
    public CurrencyCode: string;

    public static FIELD_CurrencyRates: string = 'CurrencyRates';
    public static FIELD_Id: string = 'Id';
    public static FIELD_Name: string = 'Name';
    public static FIELD_CurrencyCode: string = 'CurrencyCode';

    constructor() {
    }

    public CloneFromModel(inputModel : Currency) {  
        //CurrencyRateViewModel[]
        this.Id = inputModel.Id;
        this.Name = inputModel.Name;
        this.CurrencyCode = inputModel.CurrencyCode;   
    }

    public CloneFromViewModel(inputViewModel : CurrencyViewModel) {  
        if (inputViewModel.CurrencyRates != null) { this.CurrencyRates = inputViewModel.CurrencyRates; }
        this.Id = inputViewModel.Id;
        this.Name = inputViewModel.Name;
        this.CurrencyCode = inputViewModel.CurrencyCode;   
    }

    public GetCurrency() : Currency {
        var model : Currency = { 
            //CurrencyRateViewModel[]
            Id: this.Id,
            Name: this.Name,
            CurrencyCode: this.CurrencyCode,    
        };

        return model;
    }
}
}
```

Looking for advise, thanks.

Comment: Can you add an example of the declaration of one of the view models to the question?

Comment: @MattMcCutchen just add one, have a look. Thanks

Comment: If all of your files are global (no ES6 `import` or `export` at top level), then the `<reference path="..."/>` should have worked.

Comment: i use something like this to link the ts via reference path
`/// <reference path="../../../../../../node_modules/@privatescope/viewmodels/CurrencyRateViewModel.ts" />` could this be the reason?
`

Comment: I set up a project at https://github.com/mattmccutchen/stackoverflow-52068856 and the reference from the local directory to `CurrencyViewModel` is being resolved successfully in VS Code (of course, some other classes are missing).  You could try loading this project in VS and if it works, try to figure out what is different between it and your original project.

Comment: I am using VS2017 actually. I do believe the typescript can resolve, otherwise I couldn't run it. But what I encounter now is lots of TS2304 error in Visual Studio 2017. So I believe something wrong with configuration part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178983/discussion-between-matt-mccutchen-and-kira-hao).